# Rust web server example with GraphQL, Rocket and Postgres

Tags: rust

I'm very new to Rust and have tried to write a simple graphQL server with Rust and Postgres. It works, but I have not idea about what's good and what's bad here. I would love someone experimented to read this code.

**main.rs**

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![feature(trace_macros)]
#![plugin(rocket_codegen)]
extern crate config as rs_config;
extern crate postgres;
extern crate toml;
#[macro_use]
extern crate juniper;
extern crate juniper_rocket;
extern crate r2d2;
extern crate r2d2_postgres;
extern crate rocket;
mod config;
mod ctx;
mod database;
mod graphql;
mod routes;
mod user;

fn main() {
  let config = config::get();
  let ctx = ctx::Ctx {
    db_pool: database::db_pool(&config),
    config: config,
  };

  // create a "users" demo table
  database::uninstall(&ctx);
  database::install(&ctx);

  // lancer le serveur web
  rocket::ignite()
    .manage(ctx)
    .manage(graphql::build_schema())
    .mount(
      "/",
      routes![
        routes::post_graphql_handler,
        routes::get_graphql_handler,
        routes::graphiql,
      ],
    )
    .launch();
}
```

**routes.rs**

```
use ctx::Ctx;
use graphql::Schema;
use rocket::response::content;
use rocket::State;

#[get("/")]
pub fn graphiql() -> content::Html<String> {
  juniper_rocket::graphiql_source("/graphql")
}

#[get("/graphql?<request>")]
fn get_graphql_handler(
  context: State<Ctx>,
  request: juniper_rocket::GraphQLRequest,
  schema: State<Schema>,
) -> juniper_rocket::GraphQLResponse {
  request.execute(&schema, &context)
}

#[post("/graphql", data = "<request>")]
fn post_graphql_handler(
  context: State<Ctx>,
  request: juniper_rocket::GraphQLRequest,
  schema: State<Schema>,
) -> juniper_rocket::GraphQLResponse {
  request.execute(&schema, &context)
}
```

**user.rs**

```
use ctx::Ctx;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct User {
  pub id: Option<i32>,
  pub name: String,
  pub mail: String,
}

pub fn get_user_by_id(ctx: &Ctx, id: i32) -> Option<User> {
  let mut result = None;
  for row in &ctx
    .db_connect()
    .query("SELECT id, name, mail FROM users WHERE id = $1", &[&id])
    .expect(&format!(
      "error searching user with id {:#?}",
      &id
    )) {
    result = Some(User {
      id: Some(row.get("id")),
      name: row.get("name"),
      mail: row.get("mail"),
    });
  }
  result
}

pub fn insert_user(ctx: &Ctx, user: &User) -> Result<u64, String> {
  let rows_affected = ctx
    .db_connect()
    .execute(
      "INSERT INTO users (name, mail) VALUES ($1, $2)",
      &[&user.name, &user.mail],
    )
    .expect(&format!("error inserting user {:#?}", &user));
  if rows_affected > 0 {
    Ok(rows_affected)
  } else {
    Err(String::from(
      "No rows where affected, insert has probably failed",
    ))
  }
}
```

**config.rs**

```
use rs_config::*;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::path::Path;

/// get config from Config.toml file
/// override its values with a Config.local.toml, if exists
pub fn get() -> HashMap<String, String> {
  let mut settings = Config::default();
  settings.merge(File::with_name("Config.toml")).unwrap();
  if Path::new("Config.local.toml").exists() {
    settings
      .merge(File::with_name("Config.local.toml"))
      .unwrap();
  }
  let config = settings.try_into::<HashMap<String, String>>().unwrap();
  config
}
```

**ctx.rs**

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Ctx {
  pub db_pool: r2d2::Pool<r2d2_postgres::PostgresConnectionManager>,
  pub config: HashMap<String, String>,
}

impl Ctx {
  pub fn db_connect(&self) -> r2d2::PooledConnection<r2d2_postgres::PostgresConnectionManager> {
    self.db_pool.get().unwrap()
  }
}

// allow our ctx to be valid as a Juniper Context. It will be accessible
// with ""executor.context()" from our GraphQL resolvers
impl juniper::Context for Ctx {}
```

**database.rs**

```
use ctx::Ctx;
use r2d2_postgres::{PostgresConnectionManager, TlsMode};
use std::collections::HashMap;

// create a db connection pool
pub fn db_pool(
  config: &HashMap<String, String>,
) -> r2d2::Pool<r2d2_postgres::PostgresConnectionManager> {
  let dabatabase_uri = config.get("database_uri").unwrap().as_str();
  println!(
    "  Connection to database \"{}\" in progress ...",
    &dabatabase_uri
  );
  let manager = PostgresConnectionManager::new(dabatabase_uri, TlsMode::None).unwrap();
  let pool = r2d2::Pool::new(manager).expect("Error connecting to database!");
  println!("  Connection to database successful !");
  pool
}

pub fn install(ctx: &Ctx) {
  println!("✨  Creating users table");
  let connect = ctx.db_pool.get().unwrap();
  connect
    .execute(
      "CREATE TABLE users (
    id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    mail  VARCHAR NOT NULL
    )",
      &[],
    )
    .expect("Error while creating user table");
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
pub fn uninstall(ctx: &Ctx) {
  let connect = ctx.db_pool.get().unwrap();
  println!("️   deleting table users");
  connect
    .execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users", &[])
    .expect("error while deleting users table");
}
```

**graphql.rs**

```
use ctx::Ctx;
use user::{get_user_by_id, insert_user, User};
use juniper::{FieldError, Value};

/*******************
 * Field Query
 *******************/
pub struct Query;

graphql_object!(Query: Ctx as "Query" |&self| {
    description: "Root query object"

    field Hello() -> &str {
      "Just saying hello !"
    }

    field User(&executor, id: i32) -> Result<User, FieldError> {
      let user = get_user_by_id(&executor.context(), id);
      match user {
        Some(v) => Ok(v),
        None => Err(FieldError::new("User not found", Value::null())),
      }
    }

});

/*******************
 * Field Mutations
 *******************/
pub struct Mutation;

graphql_object!(Mutation: Ctx |&self| {
    description: "Root mutation object"

    field UserCreate(&executor, user_input: UserInput) -> Result<UserCreate, FieldError> {
      let user = User {
        id: None,
        name: user_input.name,
        mail: user_input.mail,
      };
      match insert_user(&executor.context(), &user) {
        Ok(rows_updated) => Ok(UserCreate {
          rows_updated: rows_updated as i32,
        }),
        Err(message) => Err(FieldError::new(message, Value::null())),
      }
    }

});

/*******************
 * Field User
 *******************/

// declare custom resolvers for each field of user::User
graphql_object!(User: () as "Utilisateur" |&self| {
    field name() -> &str {
        self.name.as_str()
    }
    field mail() -> &str {
        self.mail.as_str()
    }
    field id() -> Option<i32> {
      self.id
    }
});

/*************************
 * UserCreate response object
 **************************/
#[derive(Debug, GraphQLObject)]
pub struct UserCreate {
  rows_updated: i32,
}

/*************************
 * UserCreate argument
 **************************/
#[derive(Debug, GraphQLInputObject)]
pub struct UserInput {
  pub name: String,
  pub mail: String,
}

/*************************
 * Création du schema
 **************************/
pub type Schema = juniper::RootNode<'static, Query, Mutation>;

pub fn build_schema() -> Schema {
  Schema::new(Query, Mutation)
}
```

Comment: "It might be too much code for embedding it in the post" did you test ? looking at your project this look like it's small enough to fit into the character limitation. However this is an English and more generally English is the lingua franca of software programming, you should translate all your comments into English at least for the version you will put here.

Comment: @Stargateur okay i will translate and then try to put all content in the post.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I'm working on a GraphQL starter project to use as a project template: https://github.com/WillSquire/Graphy. It's very much work in progress, but might be useful